# Equation numbering

Tags: numbering, vertical-alignment, align

Suppose that when we write an equation in the `align` environment and we break the equation in two lines. There is only one equation number. How can I place this number not in the last equation line, but in the middle of the two lines?

I am writting a book in the `book` class.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `aligned` sub-environment, like this:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:my}
\begin{aligned}
10&=1+2
\\&+3+4
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

For this, the package `\usepackage{amsmath}` is needed.

Besides `aligned`, there exist also `split`, `gathered` and `multlined` (the last one is provided by `mathtools` package). All are documented in the documentation of either [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) or [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

However, this can be further improved. First, `multlined` can do its job very nicely and you don't even need any `&`s:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:my}
\begin{multlined}
10=1+2
\\+3+4
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
```

If you still prefer the alignment, some spaces at the beginnin of the 2nd line might be proper:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:my}
\begin{aligned}
10&=1+2
\\& \phantom{=} +3+4 % space of the width of `=`
\\& \quad +3+4 % fixed space
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: just curious.  why is `mathtools` needed for this?  (it's a great package, but what's asked for is provided already by `amsmath`.)  regarding formatting, the second line of your example would be improved by coding it as `&\quad{}+3+4`.

Comment: Sorry, it is not, it is only for `multlined`, which I prefer. I'll elaborate it.

Answer (score 3):

This is really only a variation on what *tohecz* did above

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}   
\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        \begin{split}
        10 =&1+2 \\
            &    +3+4
        \end{split} \\
            =& 4x - 5
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But it does illustrate how you can align across split lines (numbered as you would like) and non-split lines.

Comment: Put the `&` in front of the `=` to get the proper spacing please...

Comment: Either `&=` or `={}&`. The second form is justified here because you don't want the `+` to align with the `=`.

Comment: @egreg true, I forgot the 2nd option. I usually put `\phantom{=}` there.

Answer (score 1):

The following example is taken directly from the [`mathmode` document](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) (p 25), with small modifications to the spacing around operators:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l}
    \frac{1}{2}\Delta(f_{ij}f^{ij}) & {}={} & 2\Bigg({\displaystyle
    \sum_{i<j}}\chi_{ij}(\sigma_{i}-\sigma_{j})^{2}+f^{ij}%
    \nabla_{j}\nabla_{i}(\Delta f)+{}\\
    & & {}+\nabla_{k}f_{ij}\nabla^{k}f^{ij}+f^{ij}f^{k}[2
    \nabla_{i}R_{jk}-\nabla_{k}R_{ij}]\Bigg)
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Fundamentally, the entire equation (split in this case) is boxed in an `array` in order to make TeX think that you're still only working with a sincle equation.

Comment: however, I think that we have `aligned` and its siblings exactly to avoid doing manual tweaks like `\arraycolsep=2pt`.

Comment: @tohecz: I forgot the `\arraycolsep` in there from the example; I've modified it with my column specification `@{}c@{}`, so it's not needed anymore.

Comment: But still, you have to say `{r@{}c@{}l}` and use `{}={}`. I mean: there are situtations where this is useful, but it is very time-consuming and you make errors there easier.

Comment: @tohecz : I agree. Your proposal is faster and avoids mistakes. Plus, it works fine in an align environment.

Comment: @tohecz: In this minimal example, yes. My answer provides an alternative that might be helpful in other environments/situations.

Comment: @Werner : Thank you. Your method is also great but in my case i prefer the other proposal.